# BulkCopy.WriteToServer error for Azure Table (clustered index related)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, azure

In my asp.net page I'm trying to....

1. Create a temp datatable and fill it with data (this works)
2. Do a bulkCopy ColumnMappings on the columns to the destination table
3. Do a bulkCopy.WriteToServer from the temp datatable to the destination table

The destination table is in an Azure db.

Everything works until I try the WriteToServer, at which time I get this error:

"Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again."

My temp table and Azure destination table does have a PK. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your table might have a PK but it does not have a clustered index. Make your PK clustered.

Comment: Thanks. But, how can I do that in vb.net with my temp datatable?